# Check for Url Http status Android webview

Tags: android, webview, http-status-codes

Is there a way if I can check status code for the url I load into a webview?
I want to check if the url has anymore redirects, and if not I want to execute a piece of code.

Iam implementing the WebViewClient and I want to execute a code in the onPageFinished();

**EDIT:** The url I load is a login screen. I want to check if the user has successfully logged in.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.isEmpty()){
                    // do your stuff as you want.
                }
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // do your stuff as you want
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey, I have already implemented your answer. I want to check if the page has any more redirects. The onPageFinished is called when I load my initial url.

Comment: Use shouldOverrideUrlLoading method to check any more redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpURLConnection class.

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int code = connection.getResponseCode();
```

There you have the http code returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am loading the url in a webview. can you please explain how I can use this with a WebView

Comment: This is apart from the webview, you cant check a url with the webview without loading it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public void evaluateJavascript (String script, ValueCallback<String> resultCallback)
```